# Why is a horizontal line created, when user inputs whitespace?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

This is my code. When I'm trying to run it, for empty spaces as input it is creating a horizontal line.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [], text: '' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
} 

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit  = {this.handleSubmit}>
          <input 
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            value={this.state.text />
        </form>
        <div>
          <TodoList items={this.state.items} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
}

handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.text.length) {
        return;
    }
    const newItem = {
       text: this.state.text,

    };
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: prevState.items.concat(newItem),
      text: ''
    }));
}
}

class TodoList extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return (

         <div>

          {this.props.items.map(item => (
           <h3 key={item.id}>{item.text}</h3>
          ))}

         </div>  
       );
    }

}
```

Comment: youre missing a `}` here :   `value={this.state.text />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will always append a `<h3>` element even with whitespace as input.

And you're seeing a horizontal line probably due to the CSS styling applied to 
`h3`.

What you can do it prevent users from inserting whitespace data. One approach is to `trim()` user's input before doing length checking:

```
// In handleSubmit()
if (!this.state.text.trim().length) {
  return;
}
```

Now input with only whitespace will become 0 length and therefore exit `handleSubmit()` earlier.

---

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.props.items.map(item => <h3 key={ item.id }>{ item.text }</h3>) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [], text: '' };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ text: e.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.text.trim().length) {
      return;
    }
    const newItem = {
      text: this.state.text,

    };
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: prevState.items.concat(newItem),
      text: ''
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit }>
          <input onChange={ this.handleChange } value={ this.state.text }/>
        </form>
        <div>
          <TodoList items={ this.state.items } />
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: also could you please suggest me,when i type more text horizontal line should also adjust as per it. for now it's not working